# Plotly FigureWidgets doesn't get loaded in kaggle's notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, kaggle, ipywidgets

I am trying to create an interactive chart using plotly in Kaggle's `notebook`. My problem here is when I try to add a `FigureWidget` in the display it's says `Loading widget...` but none of the `widgets` load at all. Below, I have given an example of my problem,

**Output without `FigureWidget`**

[image: without FigureWidget]

**Output with `FigureWidget`**

[image: with Figurewidget]

**Here is the sample code**

```py
g = go.FigureWidget(data = go.Bar(x=[1,2,3,4,5],y=[1,2,3,4,5],name='xyz'),
                    layout = go.Layout(title = dict(text="title"))
                   )
container1 = widgets.HBox(children = [widgets.IntSlider(),widgets.Checkbox()])
widgets.VBox([container1,g])
```

I don't know what is the problem here. The `bar trace` works fine alone as a chart but it's not getting loaded in widgets.

Please let me know if I'm missing something. Thank you !

**P.S. : I am facing this problem in kaggle's notebook**

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change ``container1 = widgets.HBox([widgets.IntSlider(),widgets.Checkbox()])
`` to ``container1 = widgets.HBox(children=[widgets.IntSlider(),widgets.Checkbox()])`` ? And can you please add a reproduceable source to your example code? I can not replicate it by just copy pasting.

Comment: @Mike_H I tried your method but it's the same. Sorry, now I have edited the code into a more generalized one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find a solution for this `bug` with an help from [APollner](https://www.kaggle.com/aronpollner). I had to ask in `kaggle` discussion. Here is the [solution](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/questions-and-answers/350084). Hope this helps future coders!

Comment: The plots do not show after the notebook has been committed

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug for the Kaggle Notebooks.

I have found multiple posts within the Kaggle Discussion community.

For example [this](https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/202550) post 3 years ago.
As well as [this](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/135862) one just 2 years ago.

I totally see the pain in this, but apparently the Kaggle staff doesn't have this bug on the list for high priority bugs.

Hope this will change in the near future!

Comment: Ya, I saw those too. Is there any specific way to have this working? I have tried reinstalling the packages. The only thing I haven't tried is downgrading the package.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but you can try to ask the noted community posts and ask if somebody else has found a solution so far?

Comment: I got the solution and added as an answer. It seems there is an alternate way to use the widgets using `interact`.